# Android studio Mail issue

Tags: java, android-studio, gmail

I have set up classes in my app to send a mail based on the user's name email and message. It seems in app as if it's working fine but no actual email is being sent. Can Anybody help? Thank you in advance.

Here is the Gmail class i have set:

public class GMail {

```
final String emailPort = "587"; // this is gMail's smtp port number
final String smtpAuth = "true";
final String starttls = "true";
final String emailHost = "smtp.gmail.com";
String fromEmail;
String fromPassword;
List<String> toEmailList;
String emailSubject;
String emailBody;
Properties emailProperties;
Session mailSession;
MimeMessage emailMessage;

// this will be the constructor of the email
public GMail(String fromEmail, String fromPassword, List<String> toEmailList, String emailSubject, String emailBody)
{
    this.fromEmail = fromEmail;
    this.fromPassword = fromPassword;
    this.toEmailList = toEmailList;
    this.emailBody = emailBody;

    //setting the server settings for Gmail
    emailProperties = System.getProperties();
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", emailPort);
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", smtpAuth);
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", starttls);
    Log.i("Gmail", "Mail server properties are now set.");

}

public MimeMessage createEmailMessage() throws AddressException,
        MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
        mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(emailProperties, null);
        emailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail, fromEmail));//address setup
        for(String toEmail : toEmailList){
            Log.i("GMail", "toEmail" + toEmail);
            emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(toEmail));
        }
        emailMessage.setSubject(emailSubject); //email Subject
        emailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");
        return emailMessage;
}

public void sendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException
{
    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(emailHost, fromEmail, fromPassword);
    Log.i("Gmail", "allrecipients: " + emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
    Log.i("Gmail", "Your Email has successfully been sent.");
}
```

}

Here's my SendMailTask class

public class SendMailTask extends AsyncTask {

```
private ProgressDialog statusDialog;
private Activity sendMailActivity;

public SendMailTask(Activity activity) {
    sendMailActivity = activity;
}

// make the method for showing dialog progress
protected void onPreExecute() {
    statusDialog = new ProgressDialog(sendMailActivity);
    statusDialog.setMessage("Setting up..");
    statusDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    statusDialog.setCancelable(false);
    statusDialog.show();
}
//method for creation and sending of email
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... args) {
    try{
        Log.i("SendMailTask", "Setting up your email ..");
        publishProgress("Processing all your information ..");
        GMail androidEmail = new GMail(args[0].toString(),
                args[1].toString(), (List) args[2], args[3].toString(),
                args[4].toString());
        publishProgress("Preparing your information ..");
        androidEmail.createEmailMessage();
        publishProgress("Sending your information ..");
        androidEmail.sendEmail();
        publishProgress("Information sent.");
        Log.i("SendMailTask", "Information sent.");

    }catch(Exception e){
        publishProgress(e.getMessage());
        Log.e("SendMailTask", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return null;
}
// creating method for dialog messages.
@Override
public void onProgressUpdate(Object... values){
    statusDialog.setMessage(values[0].toString());
}
//method to get rid of the dialog message.
@Override
public void onPostExecute(Object result){
    statusDialog.dismiss();
}
```

}

and here is the class that im trying to get the mail sent from:

public class HelpPage extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_help_page2);

    final EditText mail1 = findViewById(R.id.email1);
    final EditText mail2 = findViewById(R.id.email2);
    final EditText nameIn = findViewById(R.id.hName1);
    final Button btnSub = findViewById(R.id.helpBtn);
    final EditText msgIn = findViewById(R.id.hMsg);
    final String password = "xxxxxxxx";
    final String sendemail = "come2gopj@gmail.com";
    final String recemail = "c2grecieve@gmail.com";
    final boolean connt;

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
            connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED){
        // Connection affirmative:)
        connt = true;
    }
    else {
        connt = false;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You're not connected to the internet",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    btnSub.setOnClickListener(
            arg0 -> {
                //method to make sure all fields are checked
                if(nameIn.getText().toString().equals("")||mail1.getText().toString().equals("")||mail2.getText().toString().equals("")||msgIn.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check you've filled all fields.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if(connt!=true){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You're internet connection needs to be checked",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    if(mail1.getText().toString().equals(mail2.getText().toString())){
                        Log.i("SendMailActivity", "Send Button Clicked.");
                        //declaring the recieving, password and sending of the email
                        List<String> toEmailList = Arrays.asList(recemail.split("\\s*,\\s*")); //Recipient List
                        Log.i("SendMailActivity", "To List: " + toEmailList);
                        String emailSubject = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.hName1)).getText().toString();
                        String emailEmail = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.email1)).getText().toString();
                        String emailBody = "User's Email : " + ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.email1)).getText().toString() + "\n" +
                                "User's message: "+((EditText) findViewById(R.id.hMsg)).getText().toString();
                        new SendMailTask(HelpPage.this).execute(sendemail, password,toEmailList,emailSubject,emailBody,emailEmail);//send the email with all the relevant data included
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AfterMail.class)); //this will start the next activity that i have included after the mail is sent
                    }
                    else{//method for checking the email inputs
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your emails don't match please try again.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                }

            });

}
```

These are the messages i get in the run dialog after I've pressed the send button:

I/SendMailActivity: Send Button Clicked.I/SendMailActivity: To List: [c2grecieve@gmail.com]

I/SendMailTask: Setting up your email ..

I/Gmail: Mail server properties are now set.

D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1205120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe1203320)

I/.myapplication: Background concurrent copying GC freed 24080(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 5(92KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 2MB/4MB, paused 1.019ms total 105.897ms

D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1205120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe1203320)

W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@af22bc6

D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1205120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe1203320)

I/chatty: uid=10085(com.example.myapplication2) RenderThread identical 5 lines

D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1205120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe1203320)

I/GMail: toEmailc2grecieve@gmail.comD/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1205120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe1203320)

D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1205120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe1203320)

I/Choreographer: Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1205120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe1203320)

D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1205120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe1203320)

D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1205120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe1203320)

D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1205120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe1203320)

D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1205120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe1203320)

D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1205120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe1203320)

D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1205120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe1203320)

I/Gmail: allrecipients: [Ljavax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;@80121b1

I/Gmail: Your Email has successfully been sent.I/SendMailTask: Information sent.

Comment: Do you notice any stacktrace logs?

Comment: Hi, there the messages I'm getting in the run dialog after I've hit the send button are above. It's probably just something simple that I am missing. Before i allowed it i even had an email from google about a less secure app trying to access the email account. I fixed that but still nothing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out what I was missing. in the GMail.java file i was missing 1 line of code to get the email to actually send. `transport.sendMessage(emailMessage, emailMessage.getAllRecipients());

That was the line i was missing. `